# CIFS mount through fstab not mounting at boot

Tags: boot, mount, fstab, cifs

Trying to auto mount two shares from my QNAP NAS onto my raspberry pi.
QNAP NAS Shares:

```
\\192.168.1.7\Disk3
\\192.168.1.7\Disk8
```

At the Raspberry Pi, created two folders:

```
/mnt/shares/NASDisk3
/mnt/shares/NASDisk8
```

fstab:

```
//192.168.1.7/Disk3 /mnt/shares/NASDisk3 cifs \
uid=1000,credentials=/etc/smbpass.txt,user,noauto,rw 0    0

//192.168.1.7/Disk8 /mnt/shares/NASDisk8 cifs \
uid=1000,credentials=/etc/smbpass.txt,user,noauto,rw 0    0
```

After boot of the Raspberry Pi only Disk3 is mounted.
Following tried without success:

- change of sequence in `fstab`
- adding `_netdev`
- checked the credentials at the NAS

Can mount Disk8 using:

```
mount //192.168.1.8/Disk8
```

However `mount -a` doesn't mount `Disk8`, and `umount cifs` result in "no cifs mounted" (according to mtab).

This is how ***mtab*** looks like after boot:

```
//192.168.1.7/Disk3 /mnt/shares/NASDisk3 cifs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,\
vers=1.0,cache=strict,username=pi,domain=NASC7B132,uid=1000,forceuid,gid=0,\
noforcegid,addr=192.168.1.7,fi$
```

and after doing `sudo mount //192.168.1.7/Disk8`, ***mtab*** contains:

```
//192.168.1.7/Disk8 /mnt/shares/NASDisk8 cifs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,\
vers=1.0,cache=strict,username=pi,domain=NASC7B132,uid=1000,forceuid,gid=0,\
noforcegid,addr=192.168.1.7,fi$
```

Still, `umount cifs` result in no cifs found.

Comment: Exchange `noauto` by `_netdev` in ***fstab***

Comment: `umount -t cifs` may be?

Comment: Script `/etc/network/if-up.d/mountnfs` usually do the mounting of all net-disks after networks is up

Comment: adding `_netdev` doesn't change anything. Only Disk3 is mounted during boot. Disk3 is the second of three 'identical' lines in `fstab`, so I assume that a network issue should result in the second AND the third line being executed ...but only the second line is, for some reason

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of problems:

1. The `noauto` flag is telling `mount` to ignore this line for `-a` mounts.  You would be able to manually attempt the mount with `mount /mnt/shares/NASDisk3`.  If you want to have this mounted at boot time then remove the `noauto` flag.
2. Your `umount` syntax is wrong; it should be `umount -t cifs`.  Otherwise you are trying to tell the system to unmount something mounted at `$PWD/cifs` which isn't what you meant :-)

Comment: removing the noauto flag works for "mount -a" and "umount -a -t cifs" but still only Disk3 is mounted during boot ...